# Can I delete ‘him’ in the sentence: They asked him if he wanted to telephone anyone.?

Tags: grammar

Can I delete ‘him’ in the sentence: They asked him if he wanted to telephone anyone. ?

I feel that I can delete the ‘him’ in the sentence, but I can not confirm.

Answer (score 1):

With 'him', the meaning is definitely that the question was asked directly of 'him'. Without 'him', it could mean the same, or it could mean that someone else was asked.